# Problem using biblatex with numeric-comp

Tags: biblatex

today I discovered a strange behaviour of the style numeric-comp. Since I'm working with larger cite lists it happend that a reference is twice in the list which results that only the first reference is cited.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
This works:
\cite{companion,knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

This is how to damage it:
\cite{knuth:ct:c,companion,knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]
Shouldn't be the output also [1-5] if I use that second cite command?

File list:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
biblatex.sty    2011/11/13 v1.7 programmable bibliographies
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
blx-compat.def    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex generic compatibility
biblatex.def    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex generic definitions
standard.bbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex bibliography style
numeric.bbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex bibliography style
numeric-comp.bbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex bibliography style
numeric-comp.cbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg    
english.lbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex localization
problem.bbl
```

My system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Artemis 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg -s texlive-full
Package: texlive-full
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: tex
Installed-Size: 90
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: texlive-base
Version: 2013.20130722-1
...

$ dpkg -s biblatex
Package: biblatex
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: tex
Installed-Size: 9392
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 1.7-1
Depends: texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-recommended, texlive-latex-extra, logreq, etoolbox (>= 2.1), dpkg (>= 1.14.18), tex-common (>= 2.00)
Recommends: biber (>= 0.9.6)
Breaks: biblatex-dw (<< 1.2o-1)
```

Comment: I am getting getting `[1-5]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xyzTz.png . May be some thing else is going on.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and newest texlive and biblatex package.

Comment: @Freude When you say 'newest' I suspect you mean 'latest included in Ubuntu': that's a very different thing. If you add `\listfiles` to your input, what version is given for `biblatex` in the 'File list' (in the `.log`)?

Comment: I use miktex which I updated today morning. May be you install texlive 2013 and update.

Comment: The output is as expected here as well (`biblatex` 2.8a, Biber 1.8).

Comment: Thanks for the question. I added more information above.

Comment: Yep. Your `biblatex` is very old, it's v1.7 from back in 2011; the current version is 2.8a. You need to update

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering why there was no update via the software repository (apt-get) during the last 3 years?

Comment: The [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) site states: "Packaging TeX Live takes a lot of work, so the latest version is often not packaged." AFAIK it is usually recommended to install a "vanilla" TeXLive system to get newer versions of certain packages. See [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated version of the package (the issue could not be reproduced with the current version of `biblatex`)?